# Is it ok to put the entire application into the $_SESSION?

Tags: php, session

I came from Desktop development and I am used to see my application in the computer's memory until it is terminated by the user. But with PHP we have to rebuild all the environment (classes, objects, database connections etc.) every time a new page is requested to the server. We store a few variables in the `$_SESSION` array to keep the user logged if he/she is authenticated.

Is it a good idea if after the user authentication, I put the `application` object (and every other objects the application created into the current session so the interpreter does not need to reload everything on every request? If it is a good idea, is it only a good if my server is dedicated?

I can't think that it wont make the response faster, and also less memory consumer.

```
<?php
    // if user and password match:
    session_start()
    $_SESSION['Application'] = new TApplication('index/index'); 
    $_SESSION['Application']->SetUser($userName);
    $_SESSION['Application']->ConfigureUserPermissions;
    $_SESSION['Application']->RUN;

<?php
    // any request after user is logged and application is set:
    session_start()
    if (isSet($_SESSION['Application']) && (!$_SESSION['Application']->GetUser = null))
    {
        $_SESSION['Application']->ExecuteAction($_GET['url']);  
    }
```

I want to know if it is:

- Possible?
- A server memory killer?
- Faster then rebuild the app by reading all `PHP` files from my `MVC`?
- Reliable approach?

Comment: As far as I understand, the `$_SESSION` variable is serialized to disk between page views, so you would still need to rebuild a your database connections, etc., every time a new request came in.

Comment: you should try it and only then you will find out why this approach is so so so bad

Comment: My intention is to develop something like a Office Application Package, with many applications that share classes and tables in the database, including user data.

Comment: @EASI: "it depends". Even Twitter and facebook engineers cannot always predict the further issues, so they solve performance issues and redesign their subsystems correspondingly as the issues appear. Do you think you're more experienced than they?

Comment: Server-cache for shared application wide resources, session possibly for user-specific resources, don't mix the two, because it would be a **waste of resources**.

Comment: My experience has been to serialize or store account variables to a database and use a reference from a cookie, or session variable, to restore them.  You still need to consider doing things efficiently but don't discredit php and whatever server you're using as being slow.

Comment: @EASI: so solve the **REAL** tasks. Get something working, then profile, then optimize if necessary. In this particular order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:** No, this is a bad idea.

**Extended answer:**

How your sessions get stored depends on your configuration. By default they are often stored in a file (one file per unique session). Sometimes they are stored in a database. Either way, this storage starts by serializing all of the data in `$_SESSION`.

Serialization is pretty speedy, but not as speedy as executing actual source code. So, having your entire application's object tree unserialized and serialized again for every request will almost certainly be slower than just executing your application. So, for performance reasons, you should not do this.

Serialization is relatively space efficient, but not nearly as space efficient as your source code. All of your application data would be serialized to disk, even the data that doesn't change per user/session. So, your list of state codes you have buried in a class somewhere? Serialized. Your map of extensions to mime types you use to handle uploads? Serialized. You'll end up with a pretty large mess of data that will quickly eat up disk space, because its basically being copied to every session instead of just existing once in your application. For space reasons and session manageability reasons, you should not do this.

Only certain kinds of data can be serialized. Anything that points to a resource, like a database connection, file handle, etc., will fail to serialize and will break when you try to use it after unserializing the objects. For compatibility reasons, you should not do this.

Memory will be utilized whether the objects are in the session or not. There is no benefit memory wise to stuffing your application in the session. The extra serialization will likely result in increased memory usage.

> the interpreter does not need to reload everything on every request

This is not actually how a modern PHP environment (or any other language environment built for the web) really works. Most if not all of your source is already preloaded. I think you underestimate the power of the environment to execute code quickly. Fighting against the interpreter and the web server is generally a bad idea. Serializing and unserializing large amounts of data is generally much much more costly than just executing all your code over again.

Session storage is not exactly cheap. It is best to put only the data you need to handle the current session, and nothing more, keeping the serialization costs low. If computing some data is slow and you don't want to re-compute it every time, then sure, find a place to store it and don't recompute it every time. If its user data, that should probably be in the database. If its specific to the session, sure, put it in `$_SESSION` for a short while, but ideally you only have a few small keys in `$_SESSION` which point to a record in a database or somewhere else that is more efficient at holding large amounts of data.